# How to create a custom template for entities?

Tags: entities

I'm having a dickens of a time overriding entity.tpl.php to create custom themes for my entities.

I am using ECK and Inline Entity Form. I've created entity `section` with bundle `masthead`. I've linked this to a node.

In a subtheme of the bootstrap theme, I then try to create a custom theme for this entity in a file called `entity--section--masthead.tpl.php` (note: I've also tried `section.tpl.php` and `section--masthead.tpl.php` and all sorts of permutations). Clear Cache. Nothing.

The [only documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1321412) is a few years old, and one of the most recent comments says this SHOULD work without the need for various hooks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add `entity` string to the template file name. These are theme hook suggestions for entity built with ECK (assuming your entity and bundle names):

1. `section.tpl.php`
2. `section--masthead.tpl.php`
3. `section--masthead--full.tpl.php`
4. `section--[ID].tpl.php`

As you can see there is a naming conflict because `section` is a drupal builtin template. It would be safer to use different name for your entity.

Comment: I can't figure how I should put a file so-named into my module (not theme) folder... because it is not loaded (it is in the template suggestions, but the entity.tpl is always loaded)

Comment: This is incorrect. The template names should be delimited with -- and not __. I have suggested an edit.